# SQL dense_rank() by group and count

Tags: sql-server

I have the following result set.

```
Tmp_Table
Tag | Code | Rel
 A     ABC    1
 A     ABC    1
 A     ABC    1
 A     ABC    1
 B     XYZ    1
 B     XYZ    1
 B     XYZ    1
 B     XYZ    1
 B     XYZ    1
 C     QWE    1
 C     QWE    1
 C     QWE    1
 D     EFG    1
```

The requirements are:

1. Group the records by tag and add a group id for each group.
2. Each group should not be more than 4 records/rows
3. Supposed groups that are more than 4 records should be split in separate groups.

I tried using `dense_rank()` to create a simple increment per record.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(Order By Tag)groupID, * FROM Tmp_Table
```

Here is the current result set.

```
groupID | Tag | Code | Rel
 1         A     ABC    1
 1         A     ABC    1
 1         A     ABC    1
 1         A     ABC    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 3         C     QWE    1
 3         C     QWE    1
 3         C     QWE    1
 4         D     EFG    1
```

The expected result.

```
groupID | Tag | Code | Rel
 1         A     ABC    1
 1         A     ABC    1
 1         A     ABC    1
 1         A     ABC    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 3         B     XYZ    1
 4         C     QWE    1
 4         C     QWE    1
 4         C     QWE    1
 5         D     EFG    1
```

I also tried using `row_number() over (partition by Tag order by Tag)` only to have a increment for each tag.

```
 groupID | Tag | Code | Rel
 1         A     ABC    1
 2         A     ABC    1
 3         A     ABC    1
 4         A     ABC    1
 1         B     XYZ    1
 2         B     XYZ    1
 3         B     XYZ    1
 4         B     XYZ    1
 5         B     XYZ    1
...
```

Surely missing something important. Any idea will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically, you should have some defining feature among your rows to ensure the order is correct (and, just in general, duplication in data without anything at all unique about the rows is redundant), but without that, here is one way you could do it with a combination of window functions (assuming SQL Server 2012+):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Tag CHAR(1), Code CHAR(3), Rel INT);
INSERT @T VALUES
('A', 'ABC', 1),
('A', 'ABC', 1),
('A', 'ABC', 1),
('A', 'ABC', 1),
('B', 'XYZ', 1),
('B', 'XYZ', 1),
('B', 'XYZ', 1),
('B', 'XYZ', 1),
('B', 'XYZ', 1),
('C', 'QWE', 1),
('C', 'QWE', 1),
('C', 'QWE', 1),
('D', 'EFG', 1);

SELECT GroupID = SUM(RN2) OVER (ORDER BY RN1), Tag, Code, Rel
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RN2 = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY RN1) % 4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM (
        SELECT *, RN1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Tag)
        FROM @T
    ) AS T
) AS T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_table', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #tmp_table;

CREATE TABLE #tmp_table (
    Tag CHAR(1),
    Code CHAR(3),
    Rel TINYINT
    );
INSERT #tmp_table (Tag, Code, Rel) VALUES
    ('A', 'ABC', 1),
    ('A', 'ABC', 1),
    ('A', 'ABC', 1),
    ('A', 'ABC', 1),
    ('B', 'XYZ', 1),
    ('B', 'XYZ', 1),
    ('B', 'XYZ', 1),
    ('B', 'XYZ', 1),
    ('B', 'XYZ', 1),
    ('C', 'QWE', 1),
    ('C', 'QWE', 1),
    ('C', 'QWE', 1),
    ('D', 'EFG', 1);

--=============================================

WITH 
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT
            tt.Tag, tt.Code, tt.Rel,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt.Tag ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            #tmp_table tt
        )
SELECT 
    GroupID = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY gv.GroupVal),
    ar.Tag, ar.Code, ar.Rel
FROM
    cte_AddRN ar
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ISNULL(NULLIF(ar.RN, 0), 4)) ) r (RN)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ISNULL(NULLIF(r.RN % 4, 0), 4)) ) m (ModRN)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ar.Tag + CAST(r.RN - m.ModRN AS VARCHAR(10))) ) gv (GroupVal);
```

Results...

```
GroupID              Tag  Code Rel
-------------------- ---- ---- ----
1                    A    ABC  1
1                    A    ABC  1
1                    A    ABC  1
1                    A    ABC  1
2                    B    XYZ  1
2                    B    XYZ  1
2                    B    XYZ  1
2                    B    XYZ  1
3                    B    XYZ  1
4                    C    QWE  1
4                    C    QWE  1
4                    C    QWE  1
5                    D    EFG  1
```

Answer (score 0):

My `#tmp_table` contains data you provided. Solution is as follows:

I add to tag 1 to record that are over four, so then on this tag you can directly apply `dense_rank()`.

```
select GroupID = dense_rank() over (order by OverFour), tag, code, rel from (
    select case when rn < 5 then tag + '0' else tag + '1' end as OverFour,
           tag, code, rel
    from (
        select rn = row_number() over (partition by tag order by tag),
        tag, code, rel
        from #tmp_table
    ) as a
) as b
```